# Recaptcha v3 Response Issue

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, recaptcha-v3

While hitting google api with secure key and token, I am getting score as 0.0 and isSuccess is coming as false. But, on Google Recaptcha Admin console, I do not see any suspicious request. The question here is if the score is 0.0 then it should come on admin console and highlighted as suspicious request but it is not. Please help me understand what am I missing? I would like to understand on what basis google calculates the score.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. please read about how to ask a great questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please consider that adding some code snippets, error logs and any useful data to help others answer your question.